# how to correctly set and retrieve glfw WindowUserPointer for callback functions

Tags: c++, glfw

Consider a simple `MouseInputHandler` which is used as a member of a `InputHandler` class. Both, the `MouseInputHandler` and the `InputHandler` have a member `InputConfig* conf` to access stuff like sensitivity and mouse speed.

This seems to work fine until i introduced the scroll callback functionality, which is initialized in the constructor of `MouseInputHandler`. I use the member function `scrollXCallback` of `MouseInputHandler` as scrollback function. To do this i needed to set the glfwWindowUserPointer with `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` and set it to the instance of `MouseInputHandler`. Additionally i needed to define a function ´func´ the gets the window user pointer and calls the actual callback function.

The problem that i am experiencing is that when the scroll callback is called the program crashes.

I found out that the `InputConf *conf` that is accessed in the member scrollback function has a different memory adress than when i access `*conf` from the `rotate` member function.

i guess it has to do with the static_cast i use in the non member callback ´func´ but i do not know how to solve this. Can somebody explain what is happening here exactly?

```
mouse.hpp
#ifndef A_MOUSEINPUT_HPP
#define A_MOUSEINPUT_HPP

#include "InputConfig.hpp"
#include "camera.hpp"

#include <glfw/glfw3.h>

struct InputConfig
{
    float speed = 0.05f;
    float defaultSpeed = 0.05f;
    float fastSpeed = 0.2f;
    float sensitivity = 150.0f;

    bool invertX = true;
    bool invertY = false;
};


class MouseInputHandler 
{
private:
    GLFWwindow *window;
    Camera *camera;
    InputConfig *conf;

    bool firstClick = true;

    // mouse state
    Vector<double, 2> lastMousePos;
    Vector<double, 2> mousePos;
    Vector<double, 3> rotationCenter;

public:
    MouseInputHandler(GLFWwindow *window, Camera *camera, InputConfig *conf):
        window(window), camera(camera), conf(conf)
    {
        // scroll callback
        // -----------
        glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, this);

        auto func = [](GLFWwindow* w, double, double yOffset)
        {
            static_cast<MouseInputHandler*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(w))->scrollX_callback(yOffset);
        };
        glfwSetScrollCallback(window, func);
    }


    void scrollX_callback(double yoffset)
    {
        float fac = conf->sensitivity; // <<<<<<<<< THIS FAILS, conf has different address here than in rotate()???
        camera->zoom(fac/10.0*yoffset);
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        updateMousePos();

        // Handles mouse inputs
        if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) == GLFW_PRESS) 
        { 
            rotate(); 
        }

        if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT) == GLFW_PRESS) 
        { 
            pan(); 
        }

        if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) == GLFW_RELEASE && glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT) == GLFW_RELEASE) 
        {
            firstClick = true;
        }
    }

private:
    void updateMousePos()
    {
        // Stores the coordinates of the cursor
        double mouseX, mouseY;

        // Fetches the coordinates of the cursor
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &mouseX, &mouseY);

        // prevent jumping view on first click
        if(firstClick) 
        {
            mousePos = Vector<double, 2>(mouseX, mouseY);
            firstClick = false;
        }
        lastMousePos = mousePos;
        mousePos = Vector<double, 2>(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    void rotate()
    {
        std::cout << conf << std::endl;
        camera->rotateX( - conf->sensitivity * dy());
        camera->rotateY( - conf->sensitivity * dx());
    }

    void pan()
    {
        camera->moveX(-conf->sensitivity/10.0*dx()); 
        camera->moveY(conf->sensitivity/10.0*dy());
    }

    float dx()
    {
        return (mousePos.x() - lastMousePos.x())/lastMousePos.x(); 
    }

    float dy()
    {
        return (mousePos.y() - lastMousePos.y())/lastMousePos.y(); 
    }

};

class InputHandler
{
private:
    GLFWwindow *window;
    InputConfig *conf;
    MouseInputHandler mouse;

public:
    InputHandler(GLFWwindow *window, Camera *camera):
        window(window), conf(new InputConfig), mouse(window, camera, conf)
    {
        std::cout << conf << std::endl; 
    }

    ~InputHandler()
    {
        delete conf;
        conf = nullptr;
    }

    GLFWwindow *getWindow()
    {
        return window;
    }

    InputConfig *getConfig()
    {
        return conf;
    }

    // call instance to handle events
    void operator()(bool doMouse, bool doKey)
    {
        if(doMouse) mouse();
    }

};

#endif
```